# When is the variable created?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I would like to know when I have specified below the variable "temp" is created ?

```
public class tempClass
{
    public string prop_temp
    {
        get
        {
            string temp = "temp";
            return temp;//When  is the variable created ?
        }
    }  
}

static void Main()
{
    tempClass x = new tempClass(); //Is the variable created now?;
    string b = x.prop_temp;//Or now ?
}
```

Comment: The below answer is correct, although so you know you could just type `return "temp";`

Comment: Your *temp* variable only exists in your program, it doesn't exist at runtime.  It plays no useful role so is eliminated by the jitter.  Just as though you'd have written `return "temp";`  String literals are also special, they are never created and never destroyed, they are simply part of the assembly metadata.  Hope that clears it up ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the variable is created when you access the property, not when you create the class.

A property getter is really "shorthand" for a method.  As such, your `temp` variable is just like any other local variable within a method, and doesn't exist until the method is run.

Answer (score 0):

Of course

```
string b = x.prop_temp;//Or now ?
```

Is where your variable `temp` is created. Check where you declared the variable, it's in `prop_temp` *property*. So it will be created when you call `prop_temp`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the variable with the item that it points to.  The variable is either just a code construct, or a pointer, depending on how you look at it.  The variables in your code are "temp", "b", and "x".  The variable "temp" will get optimized out by the compiler, and never exist.  What I think you're asking is when does the object represented by "temp" get created.  That object is in the compiled code, and exists as the code is running.  This is specifically because it is a string, and strings are immutable.  If the object had been a class, it would indeed get created (the object, not the variable) when you called the method.